# How to include Bootstraps JS dependencies

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I want to include Bootstrap 4 in my Angular 7 app. I did `npm install bootstrap --save` and the css styling works fine, but when I want to use the button for the collapsing navbar from bootstrap, the button doesn't react. I think that is because Bootstrap depends in this case on jquery and popper.js. I tried to manually include them by `npm install jquery --save` and `npm install popper.js --save`. But even after that I can't find those modules in the node_modules folder and don't know how to include those dependencies.

Help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You shoudn't use jquery with Angular. that's bad practice. You should be using ng-bootstrap, that has not dependencies on jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### This works

> ### **CHECK** [**WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-navbar-demo)

**Do npm install:~** 
**`npm i bootstrap jquery --save`**

> **OPTION 1**
>
> **Add the following in `angular.json`:~**

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    ],
```

> **OPTION 2**
>
> **Add the following link and scripts in your `index.html`**

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

**Also my `package.json` for a reference**

```
{
  "name": "angular-bootstrap-setup",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

---

**Adding node_modules screenshot for reference purpose only**

[image: node_modules folder structure]

**Hope this is helpful !**

Comment: This helped me partially. The second options makes the button work! But after I install bootstrap and jquery as advised in the first option, weirdly, I can't find a 'jquery' folder in my node_modules folder... So I can't include it. o_O

Comment: Well you could ask another question for that with more details of your problem, with a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and console errors, and screenshots if any. For this question, you can mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: You can check my `node_modules` screenshot and `package.json` for a reference

Comment: For god knows what reasons the jquery folder is now there and the option 1 now works fine for me. I'm confused but happy. Thanks so much for your kind help! 